# Uploaded content are not visible on SharePoint 2010 home page

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am very new to SharePoint 10. I have upload the file in SharePoint. Document is visible in SharePoint document library but its not visible on front end.all old files are visible on front end expect newly uplaoded files.does anyone has idea about this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled 'Content Approval' for your library? If enabled, only approved file will be visible.

And check 'Draft Item Security' also.

Comment: Yes content approval is enabled and documents are approved